# Matlab ActiveX method. Error: Missing a required parameter

Tags: vb.net, matlab, methods, activex

I'm trying to use control ActiveX in Matlab for a Mint WorkBench controller. I'm trying to use method 'VectorA', that has the following syntax according to Matlab:

```
VectorA = void VectorA(handle, int16, Variant, Variant)
```

I've read that Variant data types in Matlab are trated as cells, so my code is like this.

```
% Connecting with controller.
h=actxserver('MintControls_5812.MintController.1');
invoke(h,'SetUSBControllerLink',2); 

% Defining parameters
axes={0,1};
positions={-55.0, -60.0};

% Invoking method
invoke(h,'VectorA',length(axes), axes, positions)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error using COM.MintControls__5812_MintController_1/VectorA
Error: The parameter is incorrect.

Error in VectorA_try (line 21)
invoke(h,'VectorA',length(axes), axes, positions)
```

According to Mint's help, its syntax in Visual Basic is:

```
VectorA(nNumberOfAxes As Short, nAxesArray As Object, fPosArray As Object)
```

I tried it in VB and worked perfectly. I also have tried other syntax ways for invoking the method in Matlab, like changing ordering, data type, passing some arguments like strings, and so on, and nothing worked.

What is the correct syntax so the method works?